# Reading Common Lisp Source Code Inside Emacs?

Tags: help, common-lisp, cl

I think emacs is just brilliant. The help functionality with `C-h` is extremely useful.

Recently, I started coding in SB Common Lisp.

It would be very useful if I could search the definitions of functions for common lisp also. I realise that this may not be a default feature. Is it possible?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: [slime mode](https://slime.common-lisp.dev/) provides support for browsing Lisp documentation from Emacs, as part of a suite of features for programming in Lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part of this puzzle to to get comfortable access to the Common Lisp HyperSpec.  This snippet from my init explains how to get an info version with index:

```
      ;; Set up hyperspec lookup.  This is way more comfortable in
      ;; info-mode but takes a bit of setting up.  First get the tex files
      ;; from here: https://github.com/rebcabin/dpans2texi.  Then get a
      ;; patch to make things utf-8 friendly from here:
      ;; http://chalaev.com/f/emacs/dpans2texi.patch.  Apply the patch and
      ;; then ./configure; make; sudo make install.  You now have an info
      ;; version of the hyperspec with index (this is important).  We now
      ;; follow http://chalaev.com/emacs to make slime use this for
      ;; hyperspec lookup.  See the info-look stanza for getting info on
      ;; board. 

      ;; subvert slime doc lookup to use info
      (defvar slime-old-documentation-lookup-function
      (if (boundp 'slime-documentation-lookup-function)
        slime-documentation-lookup-function))

      (defun slime-ansicl-lookup (symbol-name)
       (interactive (list (slime-read-symbol-name "Symbol: ")))
       (info-lookup-symbol symbol-name 'lisp-mode))

      (setq slime-documentation-lookup-function 'slime-ansicl-lookup)
      (setq slime-ansicl-lookup (symbol-function 'slime-ansicl-lookup))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone will answer that there's a 3rd-party package that helps with what you ask: interact with the Common Lisp doc using some `C-h` key(s). I'm not aware of any (but you can use `eww` to browse Common Lisp documentation on the web).

However, Emacs comes with library `cl-lib.el`, which provides Elisp functions etc. that to some extent emulate Common Lisp ones.  The Elisp ones generally use the Common Lisp name but with prefix `cl-`. And Emacs provides a manual for this feature, [GNU Emacs Common Lisp Emulation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/).

Unfortunately, the *documentation* of each `cl-` function etc. is very limited.  Essentially, it typically just says that it emulates the Common Lisp function etc.  So you often can't get much of a description.

And some Common Lisp functions etc. are not emulated. There is no `cl-format` function, for example - no emulation of Common Lisp `format`.

Answer (score 1):

Package `clhs` provides a `C-h` binding option for looking up CL symbols in the CL HyperSpec: https://gitlab.com/sam-s/clhs

Answer (score 0):

Type `M-x shortdoc-display-group`, then pick a group, eg, string, and you'll get a help buffer with a short description and example for each function that operates on strings. Read more [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/emacs-builtin-elisp-cheat-sheet).

However, it is about Elisp, not Common Lisp.

Comment: OP asked about Common Lisp documentation, not Elisp.  Please clarify how your post answers the question about Common Lisp.

Comment: I specified in my answer that the help buffer I mentioned was about Elisp, not Common Lisp. However I mentioned it as I thought it might help the Vinn, since ELisp is not so far from CLisp.

Comment: Maybe @Vinn could tell us if he really meant CLisp specifically and if a help buffer for Elisp is totally unuseful to him.

Comment: I mean common lisp. SBCL. Im clear on how to read about elisp within emacs

Comment: Ok, sorry I think I misunderstood your question.